# Qjackctl output audio to Bluetooth speaker (Guitarix)

Tags: audio, fedora, bluetooth, speakers

I'm trying to setup Guitarix on my laptop running Fedora 27 using [this guide](http://libremusicproduction.com/articles/ultimate-guide-getting-started-guitarix). Everything works fine but there no audio output.

I guess it's because Qjackctl is using my laptop's internal speaker for the output. However, the internal speaker on my laptop doesn't work, I always hook up an external speaker via the audio jack.

Now, I've used the audio jack to plug in my electric guitar and connected the external speaker via Bluetooth. How can I set Qjackctl to output the audio to my Bluetooth speaker? Here's a screenshot of my setup right now.

[image]
Qjackctl uses the default settings, nothing's changed there.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?